# How do I add a Telerik grid to a page coded with Razor in a MVC project?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, telerik, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc

I've used Telerik RadGrid in asp.net projects, but I'm having trouble getting it to work in MVC/Razor.  Through some trial and error, I've managed to get a partial grid showing, but it has no data.  I'd normally bind the grid on the server side in the C# code, but since there's no code behind to MVC/Razor I'm not sure how to do that.  How do I get it to show the data from my model?

I started out by following the instructions here:
http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-mvc/using-with-the-razor-view-engine.html

```
    @Html.Telerik().Grid(Model)
    .Name("Grid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(o => o.Id).Width(100);
        columns.Bound(o => o.ApplicantFirstName).Width(200);
        })
        .Render();
    }
```

However, I received the error

> The best overloaded method match for 'Telerik.Web.Mvc.UI.ViewComponentFactory.Grid(System.Data.DataView)' has some invalid arguments   c:\inetpub\wwwroot\CarmelFinancialWeb\Views\CreateContract\CreateContract.cshtml    644 14  CarmelFinancialWeb

I then found this page:
http://markfreedman.com/index.php/2011/08/09/wrestling-with-the-telerik-mvc-grid-control-part-1/

Using the code there, I was able to figure out I needed to use the full name of my model:

```
    @{Html.Telerik().Grid<CarmelFinancialWeb.Models.ModelApplication>()
    .Name("Grid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(o => o.Id).Width(100);
        columns.Bound(o => o.ApplicantFirstName).Width(200);
        })
        .Render();
    }
```

This compiled, but I'm not getting data.  I get the two headers, no grid lines, and a message saying there are no results.

> **Id         Applicant First Name**
>
> No records to display

Some other sites I tried give some examples, but none of them have helped me display results:
[Problem rendering Telerik MVC Grid in a Razor view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4458753/problem-rendering-telerik-mvc-grid-in-a-razor-view)
[Problems with rendering a templated asp.net mvc telerik grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10631959/problems-with-rendering-a-templated-asp-net-mvc-telerik-grid)

What else am I missing?  How do I get data in the grid?

Answer (score 0):

You have to bind your Model (datasource) to the grid to display its data:

```
@{Html.Telerik().Grid<CarmelFinancialWeb.Models.ModelApplication>(Model)
    .Name("Grid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(o => o.Id).Width(100);
        columns.Bound(o => o.ApplicantFirstName).Width(200);
        })
        .Render();
    }
```

Assuming your Model is `IEnumerable<CarmelFinancialWeb.Models.ModelApplication>`

Comment: Thank you @fmgp.  When I do that, I'm back to getting this error:  The best overloaded method match for 'Telerik.Web.Mvc.UI.ViewComponentFactory.Grid<CarmelFinancialWeb.Models.ModelApplication>(string)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: Just saw your edit about being Ienumerable.  I tried to cast the model as Ienumerable, but all the Razor code (@Htlm....) broke.  How do I make it Ienumerable without breaking the rest of the code?  Assuming that can't be done, how to I bind the grid using my model as it is?

Comment: What is the type of the model ?

Comment: Forgive me, I'm new to MVC.  I didn't realize models had types.  The model is declared like this in Model.Application.cs:  public class ModelApplication
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string DealerID { get; set; }.....

Comment: On top of your Razor page (.cshtml), how did you define your @model ?

Comment: @model CarmelFinancialWeb.Models.ModelApplication
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "CreateContract";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_AdminMaster.cshtml";
    HtmlHelper.ClientValidationEnabled = true;
}

Comment: It should be @model IEnumerable<CarmelFinancialWeb.Models.ModelApplication> or something inherited

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74946/discussion-between-fmgp-and-boilers222).

Comment: I tried declaring it as IEnumerable, but it broke the rest of the page.  For example, I have a check for a variable name Model.HasMultipleContractTypes.  When I run the page, this line, which has previously been working now throws an error: 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<CarmelFinancialWeb.Models.ModelApplication>' does not contain a definition for 'HasMultipleContractTypes'